# Can't edit XAML designer in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

I'm just starting out with developing my first Android Mobile app with Visual Studio 2019 and Xamarin Forms.

I've created a demo project using Xamarin.Forms and the Master-Detail template, however when I load the designer for the Views\AboutPage.xaml, it appears to be read only.

I can not select any of the controls already on the form nor can I drag new controls on to it.

I've tried searching various keywords for this issue on google but I'm not too sure what I'm looking for. Is this by design, does something else need to be done ?

Any pointers in the right direction would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it turns out the "designer" is actually only a preview of the XAML code which has to be created by hand. Coming from a Windows Forms background, I'm going to find that very tedious... oh well.

Comment: correct, "design" XF app means writing XAML code by hand

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if your XAML Designer is enabled?
Set Enable XAML Designer check box under Tools -> Options -> XAML Designer -> General.
Then check the checkbox Enable XAML Designer. 
You'll have to restart Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes, its enabled. I can see the designer but nothing is clickable.

Comment: Are you using ReSharper? Did you add the project to a source control? Did you mark unknowingly the project folder as read only?

Comment: No ReSharper, No Source Control and I'm fairly sure its not Read Only as I can edit the source. I can't left or right click on the designer surface, it does nothing.

Comment: What if you close, re-open VS and  try to create a new project? Maybe you have to repair your VS.

Comment: I've tried updating, closing and re-opening and rebooting PC all to no avail. I will try to do a repair but its odd if that's the case as I've not really used this instance of VS2019.

Comment: I've just installed VS2019 professional as I was running community and it does the same.